# Swapping galleries inside and HTML without loads of pages

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

A relatively simple question though not simple for me!

I need to swap out content without using loads of different pages. I need to do this for a gallery and it's thumbnails.

This is precisely what I mean:

http://philipslightinfashion.co.uk/content/galleries_1

I did see some answers to this in research but all used JS and other stuff. I have no idea what the simplest method of doing this is, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Ajax is what you must try!

Comment: http://line25.com/tutorials/basic-beginners-guide-to-installing-a-jquery-lightbox

Comment: Thanks guys, I have a Lightbox implemented already, specifically I'm looking to swap out the 15 thumbnails I have in my list items with a new set of 15 thumbnails into the same div.

I will look into doing it with Ajax and Jquery

Comment: Hi guys,

Found this extremely slick plugin which I hope will solve my issue!

http://kool-swap.itsjoe.de/demo/

Answer (score 1):

You can see that post: http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2013/06/jquery-lightbox-plugins.html

There are some examples of "lightbox" and JS based galleries.

Answer (score 1):

To resolve my issue:

Used Jquery to hide and show specific DIVs when a 'next' and 'prev' link is clicked.

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
$(".galleryContent div").each(function(e) {
    if (e != 0)
        $(this).hide();
});

$("#next").click(function(){
    if ($(".galleryContent div:visible").next().length != 0)
        $(".galleryContent div:visible").next().show().prev().hide();
    else {
        $(".galleryContent div:visible").hide();
        $(".galleryContent div:first").show();
    }
    return false;
});

$("#prev").click(function(){
    if ($(".galleryContent div:visible").prev().length != 0)
        $(".galleryContent div:visible").prev().show().next().hide();
    else {
        $(".galleryContent div:visible").hide();
        $(".galleryContent div:last").show();
    }
    return false;
});
});

</script>

<div class="galleryContent">
          <!---group 1--->
             <div class="cls1">

             <ul>
                <li><a href="images/gallery/gallery_1/gallery_large.jpg" data-lightbox="philips" title="Ain't nothing but a peanut!"><img src="images/gallery/gallery_1/gallery_placeholder.jpg" width="162" height="150" alt="placeholder"></a></li>
                <li><a href="images/gallery/gallery_1/gallery_large.jpg" data-lightbox="philips" title="Ain't nothing but a peanut!"><img src="images/gallery/gallery_1/gallery_placeholder.jpg" width="162" height="150" alt="placeholder"></a></li>
                <li><a href="images/gallery/gallery_1/gallery_large.jpg" data-lightbox="philips" title="Ain't nothing but a peanut!"><img src="images/gallery/gallery_1/gallery_placeholder.jpg" width="162" height="150" alt="placeholder"></a></li>
                <li><a href="images/gallery/gallery_1/gallery_large.jpg" data-lightbox="philips" title="Ain't nothing but a peanut!"><img src="images/gallery/gallery_1/gallery_placeholder.jpg" width="162" height="150" alt="placeholder"></a></li>
                <li><a href="images/gallery/gallery_1/gallery_large.jpg" data-lightbox="philips" title="Ain't nothing but a peanut!"><img src="images/gallery/gallery_1/gallery_placeholder.jpg" width="162" height="150" alt="placeholder"></a></li>
                <li><a href="images/gallery/gallery_1/gallery_large.jpg" data-lightbox="philips" title="Ain't nothing but a peanut!"><img src="images/gallery/gallery_1/gallery_placeholder.jpg" width="162" height="150" alt="placeholder"></a></li>
                <li><a href="images/gallery/gallery_1/gallery_large.jpg" data-lightbox="philips" title="Ain't nothing but a peanut!"><img src="images/gallery/gallery_1/gallery_placeholder.jpg" width="162" height="150" alt="placeholder"></a></li>
                <li><a href="images/gallery/gallery_1/gallery_large.jpg" data-lightbox="philips" title="Ain't nothing but a peanut!"><img src="images/gallery/gallery_1/gallery_placeholder.jpg" width="162" height="150" alt="placeholder"></a></li>
                <li><a href="images/gallery/gallery_1/gallery_large.jpg" data-lightbox="philips" title="Ain't nothing but a peanut!"><img src="images/gallery/gallery_1/gallery_placeholder.jpg" width="162" height="150" alt="placeholder"></a></li>
                <li><a href="images/gallery/gallery_1/gallery_large.jpg" data-lightbox="philips" title="Ain't nothing but a peanut!"><img src="images/gallery/gallery_1/gallery_placeholder.jpg" width="162" height="150" alt="placeholder"></a></li>
                <li><a href="images/gallery/gallery_1/gallery_large.jpg" data-lightbox="philips" title="Ain't nothing but a peanut!"><img src="images/gallery/gallery_1/gallery_placeholder.jpg" width="162" height="150" alt="placeholder"></a></li>
                <li><a href="images/gallery/gallery_1/gallery_large.jpg" data-lightbox="philips" title="Ain't nothing but a peanut!"><img src="images/gallery/gallery_1/gallery_placeholder.jpg" width="162" height="150" alt="placeholder"></a></li>
                <li><a href="images/gallery/gallery_1/gallery_large.jpg" data-lightbox="philips" title="Ain't nothing but a peanut!"><img src="images/gallery/gallery_1/gallery_placeholder.jpg" width="162" height="150" alt="placeholder"></a></li>
                <li><a href="images/gallery/gallery_1/gallery_large.jpg" data-lightbox="philips" title="Ain't nothing but a peanut!"><img src="images/gallery/gallery_1/gallery_placeholder.jpg" width="162" height="150" alt="placeholder"></a></li>
                <li><a href="images/gallery/gallery_1/gallery_large.jpg" data-lightbox="philips" title="Ain't nothing but a peanut!"><img src="images/gallery/gallery_1/gallery_placeholder.jpg" width="162" height="150" alt="placeholder"></a></li>
            </ul>

             </div>

             <!---group 2--->
             <div class="cls2">
             <ul>
                <li><a href="images/gallery/gallery2_large.jpg" data-lightbox="philips" title="Ain't nothing but a peanut!"><img src="images/gallery/gallery_2/gallery2_placeholder.jpg" width="162" height="150" alt="placeholder"></a></li>
                <li><a href="images/gallery/gallery2_large.jpg" data-lightbox="philips" title="Ain't nothing but a peanut!"><img src="images/gallery/gallery_2/gallery2_placeholder.jpg" width="162" height="150" alt="placeholder"></a></li>
                <li><a href="images/gallery/gallery2_large.jpg" data-lightbox="philips" title="Ain't nothing but a peanut!"><img src="images/gallery/gallery_2/gallery2_placeholder.jpg" width="162" height="150" alt="placeholder"></a></li>
                <li><a href="images/gallery/gallery2_large.jpg" data-lightbox="philips" title="Ain't nothing but a peanut!"><img src="images/gallery/gallery_2/gallery2_placeholder.jpg" width="162" height="150" alt="placeholder"></a></li>
                <li><a href="images/gallery/gallery2_large.jpg" data-lightbox="philips" title="Ain't nothing but a peanut!"><img src="images/gallery/gallery_2/gallery2_placeholder.jpg" width="162" height="150" alt="placeholder"></a></li>
                <li><a href="images/gallery/gallery2_large.jpg" data-lightbox="philips" title="Ain't nothing but a peanut!"><img src="images/gallery/gallery_2/gallery2_placeholder.jpg" width="162" height="150" alt="placeholder"></a></li>
                <li><a href="images/gallery/gallery2_large.jpg" data-lightbox="philips" title="Ain't nothing but a peanut!"><img src="images/gallery/gallery_2/gallery2_placeholder.jpg" width="162" height="150" alt="placeholder"></a></li>
                <li><a href="images/gallery/gallery2_large.jpg" data-lightbox="philips" title="Ain't nothing but a peanut!"><img src="images/gallery/gallery_2/gallery2_placeholder.jpg" width="162" height="150" alt="placeholder"></a></li>
                <li><a href="images/gallery/gallery2_large.jpg" data-lightbox="philips" title="Ain't nothing but a peanut!"><img src="images/gallery/gallery_2/gallery2_placeholder.jpg" width="162" height="150" alt="placeholder"></a></li>
                <li><a href="images/gallery/gallery2_large.jpg" data-lightbox="philips" title="Ain't nothing but a peanut!"><img src="images/gallery/gallery_2/gallery2_placeholder.jpg" width="162" height="150" alt="placeholder"></a></li>
                <li><a href="images/gallery/gallery2_large.jpg" data-lightbox="philips" title="Ain't nothing but a peanut!"><img src="images/gallery/gallery_2/gallery2_placeholder.jpg" width="162" height="150" alt="placeholder"></a></li>
                <li><a href="images/gallery/gallery2_large.jpg" data-lightbox="philips" title="Ain't nothing but a peanut!"><img src="images/gallery/gallery_2/gallery2_placeholder.jpg" width="162" height="150" alt="placeholder"></a></li>
                <li><a href="images/gallery/gallery2_large.jpg" data-lightbox="philips" title="Ain't nothing but a peanut!"><img src="images/gallery/gallery_2/gallery2_placeholder.jpg" width="162" height="150" alt="placeholder"></a></li>
                <li><a href="images/gallery/gallery2_large.jpg" data-lightbox="philips" title="Ain't nothing but a peanut!"><img src="images/gallery/gallery_2/gallery2_placeholder.jpg" width="162" height="150" alt="placeholder"></a></li>
                <li><a href="images/gallery/gallery2_large.jpg" data-lightbox="philips" title="Ain't nothing but a peanut!"><img src="images/gallery/gallery_2/gallery2_placeholder.jpg" width="162" height="150" alt="placeholder"></a></li>
            </ul>
             </div>
```

Comment: I don't like this solution as the browser has to load ALL the images when the page loads. Using ajax would avoid this. As a bare minimum, I would implement some lazy loading of images.

Comment: True but I think it's okay as long as your not making massive galleries with tons of thumbnails. Since what I'm working on is relatively simple, this method is fine. Also I can reduce file size as much as I need in Photoshop.

But yeah in future for bigger projects I will have to use Ajax or something similar as to avoid loading times

Answer (score 0):

You should use AJAX via plain JavaScript or jQuery (or other framework). Take a look on this: [jQuery Image Gallery/](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-Image-Gallery/)